# Android, unable to add label on gridview images

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to add Captions below the images in gridview. I tried different method from google search but failed. Here is what I am trying to do right now. I am trying to do this in a fragment which is opened by another fragment. I get the following error:

```
04-01 22:02:18.331 6726-6726/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.imran.myapp, PID: 6726
                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                     at com.example.imran.myapp.AlbumImagesAdapter.getView(AlbumImagesAdapter.java:64)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
                                                     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1437)
                                                     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:361)
                                                     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:302)
                                                     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:437)
                                                     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1280)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2632)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:758)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16761)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5333)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2381)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2090)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1239)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect
04-01 22:02:18.351 1032-1110/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
04-01 22:02:18.431 1032-1110/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.imran.myapp/.Home
04-01 22:02:18.431 1032-1110/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
04-01 22:02:18.691 1032-1032/? D/CrashAnrDetector: processName: com.example.imran.myapp
04-01 22:02:18.691 1032-1032/? D/CrashAnrDetector: broadcastEvent : com.example.imran.myapp data_app_crash
04-01 22:02:19.051 1032-1059/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1241937f u0 com.example.imran.myapp/.Home t3676 f}
04-01 22:02:29.881 1032-1059/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{1241937f u0 com.example.imran.myapp/.Home t3676 f}
```

`MyAdapter`

```
public class AlbumImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public AlbumImagesAdapter(Context c, String urls[]) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = urls;
        //myurls = urls;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        //return 0;
    }
    public int imgcount(){
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public String getURL(int position){
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView imgtext;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_openalbum, parent, false);

            imgtext = new TextView(mContext);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,300));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
        } else {
            imgtext = (TextView) convertView;
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imgtext.setText("Some text");

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private String[] mThumbIds = {

    };
}
```

Most of the methods described in same type of stackoverflow questions are similar to one i used in my adapter. Can someone help me. Thanks in Advance.

Edit: `fragment_openalbum.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.imran.myapp.openalbum">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/albumname"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Album Name" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/albumdesc"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Album Description"
        />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/albumgrid"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></GridView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post your fragment_openalbum.xml layout

Comment: @Ganesj It is there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) guide should give you proper idea.

So basically you should not inflate the `R.layout.fragment_openalbum` in your Adapter's `getView()`. Instead you should create another layout to provide the view for the item of the `GridView`. For example you can create `item_gridview.xml` and it can look like this one of the two example views I gave blow. And in your `getView()` you inflate `R.layout.item_gridview` and then use `findViewById()` to get the `ImageView` and `TextView` element.

---

The stack trace  you got actually point out the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

In you Adapter, you have this:

```
imgtext = (TextView) convertView;
imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
```

Two mistakes you made here:

1. `convertView` is `android.widget.LinearLayout` which is a `ViewGroup` instead of `View` according to the stack trace exception message. But `TextView` or `ImageView` is type of `View`. So you cannot cast a type of `ViewGroup` to a type of `View`
2. You are trying to cast one object to two different type of objects. So even if `convertView` is type of `View`, it can only be either a `TextView` **OR** `ImageView`. It cannot be both.

So to your original goal:

> I am trying to add Captions below the images in grid view.

If you want to put the caption below the image, you can use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout ...
 android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        ... />
    <TextView
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or if you want to put the caption above the image, but located at the bottom of the image, you can use this layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        ... />
    <TextView
        ...
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is a very good introduction about all different layout, hope you find it helpful

https://medium.com/google-developers/layouts-attributes-and-you-9e5a4b4fe32c#.vh0l7qbvq

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not only one image or I am not using FrameLayout. The images links are obtained from database and according to number of images links, the images are added in GridView, see my updated question, I have added xml file.